# sqlite column constraint not in set of values

Tags: sqlite

In sqlite, how do I restrict the values of a column to being **not** in another table/view column?

For example

```
sqlite> create table tab1(col1 check (col1 not in (1,2)));
```

does what I want except that it seems only to exclude hard-coded values. However, the following does not work -

```
sqlite> create table tab2(vals_to_exclude);
sqlite> insert into tab2 values(1);
sqlite> insert into tab2 values(2);
sqlite> create table tab3(col1 check (col1 not in (select vals_to_exclude from tab2)));
Error: subqueries prohibited in CHECK constraints
```

Is it possible to constrain a column to exclude a dynamically determined set of values?

Comment: Background to my question - I am trying to build an adjacency list for a directed acyclic graph. I want to constrain inserts into the list to exclude cycles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the built-in mechanisms are not sufficient, implement the check manually with a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tab3_col1_not_in_tab2
BEFORE INSERT ON tab3   -- you also need a trigger for UPDATEs
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
             FROM tab2
             WHERE vals_to_exclude = NEW.col1)
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "col1 conflicts with tab2");
END;
```

or, alternatively:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tab3_col1_not_in_tab2
BEFORE INSERT ON tab3   -- you also need a trigger for UPDATEs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "col1 conflicts with tab2")
    FROM tab2
    WHERE vals_to_exclude = NEW.col1;
END;
```